# A program that prints the common multiples of two different numbers

Tags: vb.net, variables, loops, if-statement

Here's my code for this project.

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim X As Integer
    X = 0
    Do
        X = X + 1
        If X / 2 = 0 And X / 3 = 0 Then Debug.Print(X)
        System.Console.WriteLine(X)
    Loop Until (X = 100)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
```

Everthing compiles fine but it just prints the numbers 1 to a hundred. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. First, your Console.WriteLine is not part of your If statement, so it writes X regardless, which is why you see every number printed.

So that's one problem. The next problem is your If statement itself isn't correct. I think you are looking for [`Mod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) to test if a number is divisible by another:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim X As Integer
        X = 0
        Do
            X = X + 1
            If X Mod 2 = 0 And X Mod 3 = 0 Then
                Debug.Print(X)
                System.Console.WriteLine(X)
            End If
        Loop Until (X = 100)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are looking if any number is divisible by 2 *and* 3.  If that is the case, then you want to use the `Mod` function, not `/`, because no number divided by any other number = 0 unless that number itself is 0.

```
If x mod 2 = 0 and x mod 3 = 0 then
    'blah blah blah
end if
```